# Serializable class Why? and How? in Java

Tags: java, serialization

Why do you need to implement this empty interface to serialize an object?
Why if  you have to do it, the methods to serialize in a file ask for an Object instead of a Serializable? 
[ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Object obj)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeObject%28java.lang.Object%29)

How it works?

Comment: Google is the correct place to learn about this. Or the java tutorials on oracle's website.

Comment: Or, you could also read the javadoc of the Serializable interface: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html

Answer (score 2):

An object can be serialized only if it implements the Serializable interface.
There are several reasons for this:

- Serializable caracteristics of an Object should be a design state for an object and not an automatic behavior for all classes. There could be reasons why a programmer should not make a class Serializable.
- Putting sensitive informations in the class is one of these examples.
  Consider this class:

  public class Machine implements Serializable{
         private String password;
  }

This is a possible design threat for the class machine which includes a password that could be serialized. Password here should be transient if no other needs for serilaizin password are required.

- Not all objects capture useful semantics in a serialized state. The thread state is one of these examples.

The ObjectOutput has methods that allow objects to be written to a streamed content which could be done not only by Serialiazaton. ObjectOutputStream for example needs  objects that implements Serialaizable.

Answer (score 1):

These are called `tag` or `marker` `interfaces`; the following extract from the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern) explains it quite well. Please also give attention to criticism of the pattern on that article.

> An example of the application of marker interfaces from the Java
>   programming language is the `Serializable`   interface. A class
>   implements this interface to indicate that its non-transient data
>   members can be written to an `ObjectOutputStream`   . The
>   `ObjectOutputStream` private method `writeObject()` contains a series of
>   `instanceof` tests to determine writeability, one of which looks for the
>   `Serializable` interface. If any of these tests fails, the method throws
>   a `NotSerializableException`.

Comment: I was thinking the same, but in that case why the writeObject method ask for an object instead of a Serializable?

Comment: The ObjectOutput has methods that allow objects to be written to a streamed content which could be done not only by Serialiazaton. ObjectOutputStream for example needs objects that implements Serialaizable.